# How to create post request using angular.js and drywall (user management system) which needs csrf token?

Tags: angularjs, post, drywall

How to create post request using angular.js and drywall (user management system) which needs csrf token ?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information or a little bit of code of your side would be helpful. But I'll try:

A basic POST request would look sth like this:

```
function login() {
  return $http.post('your-domain.com', {someData: "foobar"}).success(function(response) {
    // do something with your data
  }).error(function(error) {
    // do something with the error
  });
}
```

If you want to include the CSRF token for every request, you can read it out of your HTML code, and use the `$http.defaults.headers` object. Inside your `app.js` do this:

```
var yourApp = angular.module("yourApp", [
]).config(function() {
}).run(function($http) {
  var csfrToken = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csfrToken;
});
```

Depending on your framework that generates the CSRF token, you have to adjust the jQuery selector `$("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")`.